# On edit, use selected in select form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I've got a select in my form with all the groups. So I loop through all available groups.

However; When I try to edit a client, the selectbox doesn't add a selected to the group i've selected. Most likely because of the loop in it. How can I make the right one selected?

`<%= f.select(:group_id, options_for_select(@usersGroups.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }), :prompt => "Kies een groep") %>`

Comment: You can also do it like <%= f.select(:group_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@usersGroups.all,name,id), :prompt => "Kies een groep") %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[options_for_select documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

So in your situation probably something like:

```
<%= f.select(:group_id, options_for_select(@usersGroups.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, @client.group_id), :prompt => "Kies een groep") %>
```